# Filtering MySQL query only when the filter values are not empty-string, white-space or null best practice

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, where-clause, isnullorempty

I want to filter the values here for say columnA, then by columnB etc, however I would like that if the filter valueA is simply an emptystring, that no filtering occurs and all values are accepted. The same for say valueB if that were empty then no filtering would occur.

This is a generic mysql query, where I would hope to only filter when the valueA or valueB (inclusive or) has a value that is not null, whitespace or empty string.

```
   using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(
                    " SELECT columnA, columnB etc
                    " FROM table" +
                    " WHERE columnA = '" + valueA + "' " +
                    " THEN BY columnB = '" + valueB + "' " +
                    " GROUP BY columnA" +
                    " LIMIT 0, 100",
                    connection))
```

Comment: You should be using parameters, not concatenation - otherwise your query will break if `valueA` contains an apostrophe, for example.

Comment: Or worse, you end up being the one responsibe for [causing this](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3009236/massive-vtech-hack-exposes-data-of-nearly-5-million-parents-and-over-200-000-kids.html)

Comment: Thanx, I wasn't aware there is a better method for inserting the value of a where clause. Can you elaborate pls?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com talks in some depth about the risk of building SQL strings using concat'd values, and gives examples on how to avoid it in your code. In essence, SQL is a programming language all of its own, that you're putting inside your app, that is sent somewhere else, compiled and run. If you let someone stick any old thing into the middle of the program, it's a biiig security hole; they don't need to bust the password to get into your database, they can just get your code to run their code for them

Comment: thanx, this is the injection vulnerabilities i am guessing?

Comment: would this be a better where statement?                                       
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnA = @columnA

Comment: Definitely.. Something that came up in convo with a colleague about SQLinj - they thought that the `@x` was just some placeholder in the string in C#, and that if the `@x` value was set to `'; DROP TABLE Students--` that C# would sub it and the injection would still occur. Eventually I got the point across that it effectively creates a variable in the SQL code that "goes all the way to the database, so that the DB knows the parameter contents provided is merely a string value, not code.. Just in case that was a point of confusion; it's telling the db "this `';DROP ..` is string data, not code"

Comment: thanx for enlightening me, I don't have too much code to update and it's code in my company so I can convert it without hassle.

Answer (score 1):

- SQL, as a language, does not support dynamic predicates.

  - The ISO SQL design committee knows this, and they take glee from seeing us all suffer from having to use their horribly unergonomic and excessively verbose query language.
- To have conditional predicates or dynamic predicates you will need to rebuild your query using some form of string concatenation.

  - Some people suggest making query parameters `NULL`able and abusing `@value IS NULL OR [Column] = @value` however **this is (potentially) a horrible thing to do** in production databases because (even as of 2021) I'm not aware of any major RDMBS handling this case properly and you end-up with very, very poor performing execution plans.

In your case, do something like this:

```cs
String sql;
List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();

{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "SELECT columnA, columnB, FROM table" ).AppendLine();
    
    List<String> predicates = new List<String>();
    if( valueA != null )
    {
        predicates.Add( "columnA = @pA" );
        parameters.Add( new MySqlParameter( "@pA", valueA ) );
    }

    if( valueB != null )
    {
        predicates.Add( "columnB = @pB" );
        parameters.Add( new MySqlParameter( "@pB", valueB ) );
    }

    // etc
    
    if( predicates.Count > 0 )
    {
        _ = sb.AppendLine( "WHERE" );
        _ = sb.AppendLine( String.Join( " AND ", predicates ) );
    }

    //

    _ = sb.AppendLine( "ORDER BY foo GROUP BY bar LIMIT 0, 100" );

    sql = sb.ToString();
}

using( var cmd = new MySqlCommand( sql, connection ) )
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange( parameters );

    cmd.Execute...
}
```

Comment: Also, side pondering, is your "return value is unused" analyzer more aggressive than most?

Comment: @CaiusJard It is - I know it sounds frivolous but since setting that to a Warning (instead of being disabled) I've found (and prevented) countless bugs in my programming code. Ditto for unused method parameters. (But it's very weird that C# still doesn't warn when a readonly property is never set (the `#nullable` warnings don't apply for value-type properties or for nullable ref-type properties).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `OR` logic, and checking on the C# side for whitespace is easier

> Note the use of parameterization to prevent SQL injection

> Note the use of a multi-line string to make the query easier to read

```cs
const string query = @"
SELECT columnA, MAX(columnB) etc
FROM table
WHERE (columnA = @valueA OR @valueA IS NULL)
  AND (columnB = @valueB OR @valueB IS NULL)
GROUP BY columnA
LIMIT 0, 100;
";
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueA", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueA) ? (object)DBNull.Value : valueA);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueB", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueB) ? (object)DBNull.Value : valueB);
```

Performance may not be great on large tables, so you may need to use completely separate queries

Comment: Don't do this. It will have very poor performance because SQL query engines don't treat `( x = @x OR @x IS NULL )`-style predicates as SARGable as well as wrecking cached execution plans. If MySQL does then I'll eat my words, but Oracle, MS SQL, and others don't handle this case well.

Comment: I'm sure I've read something somewhere about how MySQL handles queries of this nature, i.e. where it can determine that eg `@valueA IS NULL` is always true, it removes the entire predicate.. Can't find it now, but I think it was in the official docs, doing some deepdive about how the optimizer rewrites queries..